# Self signed certificate not trusted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, certificate, https

I have created my own CA:

```
openssl genrsa -out private/rootCA.key 2048
openssl req -batch -new -x509 -nodes -key private/rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -config ./openssl.conf -out certs/rootCA.pem
```

I have created a certificate for my site:

```
openssl genrsa -out private/$domain.key 2048
openssl req -batch -new -key private/$domain.key -config ./openssl.conf -subj "/commonName=$domain" -out csr/$domain.csr
openssl x509 -req -in csr/$domain.csr -CA certs/rootCA.pem -CAkey private/rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out certs/$domain.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

I join the site cert and the root cert into a bundle:

```
cat certs/$domain.crt certs/rootCA.pem > bundles/$domain.bundle.crt
```

I copy the cert / key to the nginx config dir:

```
cp bundles/$domain.bundle.crt private/$domain.key /etc/nginx/conf/certs
```

I make sure that nginx uses those certs for my site:

```
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/mysite.bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/mysite.key;
```

I restart nginx.

I install the root cert in my system:

```
sudo cp certs/rootCA.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myrootCA.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

I verify with `httpie`:

» http https://mysite

```
http: error: SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mysite', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

I verify with `openssl` (telling it to use the ca-certificates dir, which is not used by default it seems):

```
openssl s_client -host mysite -port 443 -prexit -showcerts -CApath /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
```

Which gives:

```
Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

And verification does not complete.

Opening the site in Chrome gives me the standard error:

> This server could not prove that it is mysite; its security
>   certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This
>   may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your
>   connection.

I have two questions:

1. Why is the site not trusted, system-wide, after installing the root cert? Chrome is using system-wide cerficates, right?
2. Why is `open_ssl s_client` not able to complete the cert validation?

### EDIT

Curl is working, with the system-wide installed cert:

```
curl https://mysite
```

Why is curl working and chrome/httpie not?

Comment: Well does your cert actually contain the hostname `registry.dgvmetro`? Did you verify that your root cert contains the `v3_ca` extension or similar?

Comment: Stop self signed certificate, use `let's encrypt`

Comment: @GillesQuenot There is absolutely nothing wrong with self-signed certificates.  Bottom line, Let’s Encrypt certificates, are basically self-signed certificates anyways but the root authority is trusted by all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

**For OpenSSL** Ubuntu `update-ca-certificates` as described on its man page *reads* from `/usr/share/ca-certificates` AND `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` but writes symlinks with the **subjhash.num names needed** by OpenSSL to `/etc/ssl/certs` and a combined file in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` so the latter two should be used with `-CApath` and/or `-CAfile` respectively.

`curl` apparently uses the OpenSSL default, which in this build is `/etc/ssl/certs/`, but depending on which Ubuntu, OpenSSL may be old enough to have the bug that commandline `s_client` does NOT use the default automatically.

**For Chrome** I can't help; I don't use Chrome on Ubuntu. Left CW in case someone else can.

Although I do know once you get the CA trusted, recent Chrome also requires your *server* cert (in PKI terms, End Entity = EE = not CA) have a SAN extension (SubjectAlternateNames) with the correct name(s), which neither of the others do (for now), and you don't indicate if/how you did that. (expanded:) rfc 2818 for HTTPS and the CABforum standards have for over a decade required server certs to contain valid SAN, and by now all or nearly all clients *use* SAN when present, but to my knowledge so far Chrome is the only client that *requires* SAN be present.

Comment: ee cert means [Easy Engine](https://easyengine.io/docs/lets-encrypt/) ? I am using a self-generated CA and cert.

Comment: @dangonfast: edited

Answer (score 0):

It seems my self-generated root CA was wrong. It was missing:

```
basicConstraints               = CA:TRUE
```

After solving this, `httpie` is behaving properly. It is strange that `curl` was not complaining about this.

This is not yet solving the problem in Chrome though ... I assume that Chrome does not use system-wide CAs.

Comment: Chrome generally should use the platform's truststore -- but not necessarily the PEM-format one. (I use it on Windows and there it definitely does use the Windows store. That's why I left that part of my answer open.)

Comment: “I assume that Chrome does not use system-wide CAs.” - You would be mistaken.  Chrome trusts the OS and/or user’s certificate store.  Since you solved your original problem, might consider removing your additional question, and submitting a different question to get the answer to it.  Be sure to isolate the information, we don’t need everything, we needed for the original problem

Comment: @Ramhound [yessir!](https://superuser.com/q/1306144/94612)